# How to request CMake to be not verbose?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Every time I launch `make` (generated from CMake), each build step is introduced with multiple lines formatted this way:

```
[100%] Built target foobar
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/foobar
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /home/me/git/master/build/debug »
```

That goes from 0% up to 100%. So every time I launch `make`, it outputs a lot of lines. A lot. That's very verbose and warnings get lost in the process.

How can I ask CMake to remove all that, and generate `Makefile`s that will get `make` to output only the compiler output?

Comment: make > /dev/null, you still get compiler error messages printed out since they go to stderr.

Comment: @virtus Indeed it works. I feel dump. I was thinking that gcc was outputing that on the standard output... as long as it is not gcc's internal error. Make an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
make > /dev/null
```

You still get compiler error messages printed out since they go to stderr.